# Bandwidth rate for specific IP (bash scripting)

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, 22.04, bandwidth

I can watch live bandwidth rate using `tcptrack -i ens3 src or dst IP`

But I need to use it in bash script

Are any tools which could return current bandwidth rate for given IP?

Like in tcptrack in the bottom 'Total' section
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iftop` is more flexible in bash script than `tcptrack`. Here is an example:

```
sudo iftop -B -F IP -i ens3 -t -s 2 > log
```

`-t` option to use the text interface, `-s 2` to execute `iftop` for 2 seconds, then quit. `> log` to redirect the results to a log file. Then you be able to parse your log file easily.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the solution I was looking for